# Ubuntu 18.04.1 - Won't change the IP address to be static

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1-LTS under Windows 10 using the Windows Store Hyper-V image.

However when I go and try to change the IP address to be static by using the GUI as follows:

[image]

even after toggling the interface Off and then On it still shows a 172.x.x.x address:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does your static IP agree with the VM's Virtual Network Adapter?

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the nudge. It was a Hyper-V virtual switch issue. If you want to add your comment as an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VM's Virtual Network Adapter is set to support a given range of IPs.

The static IP must be in that range to be acceptable.